# How to get OnClick() Event inside an Embedded PDF Reader using Embed Tag in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have an Angular component which has an Embedded PDF Reader which is made using  tag in HTML. The code is given below.

```html
<embed id="htmlObjectElement" [attr.src]="pdfSource" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" (mouseenter)="onMouseEnter()">
```

How can I catch a OnClick() Event inside this embedded pdf.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `(click)` event as specified [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#binding-to-user-input-events) in the angular doc ?